# Javascript: For loop in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm doing a scoring app as practice, and I'm trying to get an object to calculate the total score for a player. Here is the part I'm struggling with:

```
totalScore: function () {
  "use strict";
  debugger;
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.players[i].length; i++) {
    for (var n = 0; n < this.players[i].score[n].length; n++) {
      sum += this.players[i].score[n];
    }
    this.players[i].totalScore = sum;
  }  }
```

So I have a main object `scoreTable`. `players` is an array of objects which includes another array called `score`. So what I'm trying to do is create a `totalScore` object function that runs a loop through the `players` array that loops on each `score` array and finds the sum of that array.

I don't know why, but when I run through it on the dubugger, it goes into the first for loop, finds the first array of players, then just skips to the end of the function without running the next loop. I'm not sure why it's doing that.

Comment: I bet sum must be inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.players[i].length; i++) {
    for (var n = 0; n < this.players[i].score[n].length; n++) 
}
```

This should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++) {
    for (var n = 0; n < this.players[i].score.length; n++) 
}
```

Comment: and the next for loop too `score.length`

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
totalScore: function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++) {
        var player = this.players[i];
        player.totalScore = 0;
        for (var n = 0; n < player.score.length; n++) {
          player.totalScore += player.score[n];
        }
    }
}
```

This fixes not only syntax errors, but also the sum-logic itself: `sum` variable from initial post won't reset for each new player in the top-level loop.